# Deriving the dephasing operator in the master equation for atom laser interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, laser, decoherence

Consider a two level atom where the two levels of the atom are seperated by energy $\hbar\omega_{0}$ and are coupled via the dipole interaction induced by interaction with a laser of fluctuating frequency, $\omega$. The probability distribution of this laser frequency could be given by a Lorentzian distribution:
$$P(\omega)=\frac{\gamma/2\pi}{(\omega-\omega_{1})^{2}+(\gamma/2)^{2}}$$ where $\omega_{1}\approx\omega_{0}$. In this case, the classical noise in laser frequency gives rise to dephasing in the form of a $\sigma_{z}=|g\rangle\langle g|- |e\rangle\langle e|$ collapse operator in the Lindblad master equation associated to damping rate, $\gamma$. I am trying to find a derivation of this operator, if someone could recommend a resource it would be greatly appreciated.

As far as I understand, this dephasing describes fast fluctuations of the laser frequency according to $P(\omega)$, such that the atom is interaction with a single frequency at any given time. The motivation behind my question is to understand what happens in the following scenarios.

(1) Slow fluctuations in the laser frequency, such that the atom is only interacting with one frequency throughout a pulse, but this frequency is varying randomly and hence when an experiment is repeated many times we observe an average effect of the dynamics.

(2) No fluctuation in the laser frequency, but the atom is always interacting with a distribution of intensities, given by $$I(\omega)=\frac{\gamma/2\pi}{(\omega-\omega_{1})^{2}+(\gamma/2)^{2}}.$$

If anyone could shed any light on how (or if) these two scenarios differ from the first it would be really appreciated.

Comment: How can there be distribution of intensities in 2), if there is no fluctuation in frequency? Frequency $\omega$ in spectroscopic functions like $I(\omega)$ always refers to frequency of an harmonic function, which is a part of the Fourier basis, and has zero width $I(\omega)$. Non-zero width of $I(\omega)$ means the field is not such harmonic function, but a superposition, it has no single frequency, and this can manifest either via the wave not being harmonic, or "looking like" harmonic on short time scale, but changing frequency on long time scale.